# Bundle multiple SQL insert statements in Slick

Tags: java, scala

I have following scenario

(1) Java App -- calling --> (2) Scala Facade Service -- calling --> (3) Scala Service -- running query --> (4) DB

So I have basically four layers, the thing is query run by (3) Scala Service takes long time but guarantee to complete. (1) Java App is not needed to wait for the result so i want to send OK to Java App as soon as Facade make call to service.

So far I have following code in facade

```
def doSomeOperation(): Future[WSResponse] = {
  service.doSomeWorkOnDB()
}
```

So how I can make it return OK as soon as it make call to `service.doSomeWorkOnDB()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
def doSomeOperation(): Future[WSResponse] = {
  service.doSomeWorkOnDB()
  Future.successful(ok())
}
```